# Getting Error with memoized_finder method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, memoization

I trying to implement a memoized_finder method and I am getting an error that I don't understand.

My method follows:

```
class Module
def memoized_finder(name, conditions=nil)
class_eval <<-STR
  def #{name}(reload=false)
    @#{name} = nil if reload
    @#{name} ||= find(:all, :conditions => #{conditions.inspect})
  end
STR
end
end
```

This is resulting in the following error:

```
SyntaxError: (eval):3: odd number list for Hash.    @sire ||= find(:all, :conditions => {conditions.inspect})
```

I have googled around but can't come up with what is going wrong.

Note: The method I'm using come from a great article on Extending Activerecord Associations. Here's the link if anyone want's to have a look:http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/1/9/extending-activerecord-associations

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my jruby installation is based upon a version of rails that is not compatible with the memoized_finder method.